# Can a projection operator increase the $L_\infty$ norm?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $P$ is a $n\times n$ matrix of real values satisfying $P^2=P$ so that $P$ is a projection matrix. Is it possible that

$$\|Px\|_\infty > \|x\|_\infty$$

for some $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$? Here $\|y\|_\infty := \max_i |y_i|~.$

If possible, please give an example. If not possible, how can I prove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the following matrix $A$ written in the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$:

\begin{pmatrix}
3 & -6  \\
1 & -2  
\end{pmatrix}
It is idempotent ($A^2=A$) and if you take the vector $v = \begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
0
\end{pmatrix}$ then $\vert\vert v \vert\vert_{\infty} = 1$ and $\vert\vert Av \vert\vert_{\infty} = 3$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in fact we can find an *orthogonal* projection with this property. If $u = (4/5,3/5)^T,$ $v = (1,1)^T$, and $P = uu^T$, then we find that
$$
Pv = u(u^Tv) = \frac 7{25}(4,3)^T  = (1.12,0.84)^T.
$$
We find that $\|Pv\|_\infty = 1.12 > \|v\|_\infty = 1$.

---

In fact, I would conjecture that if $x$ is a vector whose entries are of equal absolute value and $P$ is any orthogonal projection onto a subspace not containing any of the the standard axes, then we will necessarily have $\|Px\|_\infty > \|x\|_\infty$.

Comment: Interesting conjecture Ben. Thanks!